# Fedora apache server

Tags: apache, certificate, fedora

I've created two virtual hosts on Fedora. I have a `websites.config` file in `/etc/httpd/conf.d` directory:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.beratyeniceri.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/beratyeniceri.com/public_html
ServerAlias beratyeniceri.com
SSLEngine ON
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/certs/beratyeniceri.com/1000.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/certs/beratyeniceri.com/beratyeniceri.key
ErrorLog logs/virtual.host-error_log
CustomLog logs/virtual.host-access_log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.tugbanursari.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/tugbanursari.com/public_html
ServerAlias tugbanursari.com
SSLEngine ON
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/certs/tugbanursari.com/1001.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/certs/tugbanursari.com/tugbanur.key
ErrorLog logs/virtual.host-error_log
CustomLog logs/virtual.host-access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I run,

```
service httpd restart
```

it asks pass phrase for `tugbanursari.com`, but does not ask for beratyeniceri.com. When I switch their spot, then it only ask for second block. Hence,it skip first site which is on first block. Then, I think it does not work.

1. How do I fix that?
2. What is my server ip address to change hosts file for clients?

Comment: If you run **apachectl configtest** does it show any errors?

Comment: @user2182349 No. İt says "syntax ok."

Comment: Are you planning to require the pass phrase for restarts?  You may want to change the certs to not require a pass phrase in case Apache is restarted by the system, in which case it would not start because the system wouldn't enter the pass phrase.